# Menu desplegable y cambio de frames

Tags: menu, ventana

Hola muy buenas noches a todos como esta?, bueno les comento una duda que tengo respecto de la interfaz grafica que no estoy pudiendo resolver hace varios dias

resulta lo siguiente:
estoy diseñado un programa de calculo aeronautico, con lo cual la ventana principal, las geometrias, colores y diseños de la ventana estan hechas ya, incluso los menues con sus cascadas y comando de ejecucion a las que no tiene que tener cascada, hasta alli todo muy bien.
mi problema viene cuando quiero usar los frames paga cambiar de pagina, disculpen si no soy muy tecnico, es de hobby, osea por ejemplo, al accionar menu archivo, lo clasico, abrir guardar salir, pero por ejemplo cuando selecciono Variables de entorno o alguno de sus submenues me vuelque todo en la la ventana.
por separado no tengo inconvenientes, es mas trabajo con varios ejemplos distintos y me va bien, el problema es querer fucionar, alguno podria ayudarme, quizas sea una pavada y ofende a la comunidad, en ese caso perdon, mis conocimientos son inquietos pero no llegan a tanto, cordiales saludos y a la espera de cualquier respuesta

Comment: Hola Lucas, bienvenido, realmente no entiendo cual es tu problema, encima sin ver el código que tienes, sin saber de que lenguaje estás hablando... se hace difícil, ayudanos a ayudarte, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, luego edita tu pregunta, agrega tu código, y haremos lo posible para ayudarte, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una

Comment: Tienes razón. Olvide las cosas más importantes. Subiré el código en python a ver si es más fácil así. Gracias